# Creating a smooth function which is positive on some arbitrary open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

I am looking for a $C^\infty$ function which is positive on an arbitrary open $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and is zero on the boundary of $U$. Furthermore, the differential of the function on the boundary should not be zero.

How can such a function be constructed?

Comment: You don't care about the values outside of U?

Comment: Suppose U is the interior of a square in the plane. Can you do it? Compute the derivativesin the direction of the sides at a vertex.

Comment: @Mariano Now I understand why it can't be done. Feel free to make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a believe to be an example of such a function.

Let's consider first $ V \subset \mathbb{R} $, where $ V = ( a, b ) $ is an open set for some real numbers $ a, b \in \mathbb{R} $.

Consider the function
$\ f : V \to ( 0, 1 ) $ defined by:

$ f(x) = \mathrm{sin} \left(  \frac{  \pi\ (x-a) } { b-a } \right) $

A quick plot:

[image: A quick plot:]

We see that $\ f(x)>0$ always positive for $x \in ( a, b ) $. In addition to this, the derivative of $\ f$ is non zero at $x=a$ and $x=b$. This function is also $C^{\infty}$.

Now let's generalize this. Consider the set $ U = ( a_{1}, b_{1} ) \times ( a_{2}, b_{2} ) \times \times ..... \times ( a_{n}, b_{n} ) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $, where $a_{1}, a_{2}, .....a_{n}, b_{1}, b_{2}, ..... b_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the function $\ g : U \to ( 0, 1 ) $ defined by:

$g(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) = $  $\mathrm{sin} \left(  \frac{  \pi\ (x_{1}-a_{1}) } { b_{1}-a_{1} } \right) $ $\mathrm{sin} \left(  \frac{  \pi\ (x_{2}-a_{2}) } { b_{2}-a_{2} } \right) $ ..... $\mathrm{sin} \left(  \frac{  \pi\ (x_{n}-a_{n}) } { b_{n}-a_{n} } \right) $

That function is positive for every value on the set $U$ (which is an open "box" of numbers in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Somebody call me out on this if I'm wrong.

Comment: In the definition of $g$ is that $x_1 - a_1$, $x_2 - a_2$.... ? Also I think the differential will be zero at the "corner", as suggested by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez in the comment.

Comment: That is true, I didn't think about that. However, what if we shift the entire function down: $g(x_{1},...,x_{2})$ - p, for some small number p. For example in two dimensions:

Comment: I think it has more to do with the smoothness of the boundary. Every smooth functions $f$ that is zero at the boundary of a square has to has $\nabla f=0$ at the corner.